# Merging two accounts at math.stackexchange

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

Merging two accounts. I have logged into math.stackexchange with a different openid and unfortunately now I have two([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/149/prasoon-saurav) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2130/prasoon-saurav)) accounts at math.stackexchange. Please its my request that the two accounts shall be merged.

Comment: For everyone who wants to have accounts merged, you could also flag one of your posts for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

Done. 2130 is now merged into 149.